# Where SBODI_Server library is save?

Tags: sapb1

I need to create a C # project that uses the DI server library. But I do not know where the libray is saved.

I reinstalled the SDK (and enabled to add the Di server library), but when I try to add it as a reference, I do not find it.

I'm using VS2017 and SAP 9.3.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUIkU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If it's installed correctly it should show up as a COM reference called "SAP Business One DI Server API". See https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3776529

The default installation location is *C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SAP Business One ServerTools\DI_Server*

Note that if you're going to use it in a web service hosted under IIS, you have to set DCOM security to enable it to be instantiated. In Component Services it's called "SBODI_Server".

Comment: Thanks! I removed all SAP components and reinstall and enable the DCOM security and worked.

Comment: @BrunoFagundes great to hear. Please accept the answer if you're happy with it.